# Android set background from filepath

Tags: android

I would like to do something similar to `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);` but instead of providing an image from my app's resources, I would like to point to a file (`/sdcard/.../image.jpg`).

Is there a way to do that that does not involve loading the Bitmap and then setting the bitmap to the imageview ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String filePath)`.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher This creates a bitmap, I am looking for a way not to do that to save some resource

Answer (score 5):

You can update background from SDCard as follows...

```
String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/" + "image.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Why do you need the first two lines?  You can just do `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);` and then `new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)` - you don't need resources for that.

Comment: Thanks but I am asking if there is a way <em>not</em> to load the bitmap. (because of out of memory errors)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
public Bitmap ImgBitFromFile(String file_name) {

    File imgFile = new File(file_name);

    if (imgFile.exists()) {

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        return myBitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And used like:

```
    img.setImageBitmap(ImgBitFromFile(File_Path));
```

And do not Forget to add READ Permission in your `manifest.xml` file.

Comment: DON'T use `System.out.println` in an android app.  Use `Log.d` instead.